# maximum number of possible rules of a sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, philosophy

Read this
http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/sequences-finding-rule.html
and also
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Oxford_Murders_%28film%29
where the scene about the murder note left behind contains a sequence of numbers, and it is said that the next number can be pretty much anything

a few more googling eventually lead me into this
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wittgenstein_on_Rules_and_Private_Language
which said that all rules are subjected to interpretations, and that you cannto be sure which is the correct one

So my question then becomes:

Given a sequence

$$S=a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4 \cdots$$

What is the maximum number of possible rules that can be used to produce the next term, or is it impossible in general for all sequences S to have a finite number of rules that can produce all given terms and the next terms?

A more concrete example:

$$S_1=1,1,2,3 \cdots$$

We knew that one of the rules that fit $S_1$ is the Fibonacci Sequence, but is there a maximum number of rules that can fit $S_1$ but does **NOT** generate the Fibonacci Sequence?

If we have a function F(S,$\lambda$) which is defined as follows

$$F(S,\lambda)=max(no. of rules for a given S)$$

where S is a sequence and $\lambda$ is the number of known first few terms in the sequence (e.g. $\lambda$=2 means we are given $a_1,a_2$

What is the first starting point in choosing S (so as to make it less ambigurious) such that the behavior of F can be investigated without loss of (too much) generality?

Comment: There are at least countably many such rules that would fit any given sequence.  For example, if $S_1 = 1, 1, 2, 3, 5,...$, I could have an infinity of rules that uniquely specify the $6$th, $7$th, etc., etc., term in the sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure that $F$ is always infinite. Given sequence $S = a_1, a_2, \dotsc$ with $\lambda = 2$, we can consider these as two points $(1,a_1)$ and $(2,a_2)$. Given these two points, there are a countably infinite number of cubic polynomials that satisfy these two points (one for each integer choice of $a_3$). 
We can say that our rule is $a_i = fi^2 + gi + h$ for the $f,g,h$ that agree with our first two terms $a_1$ and $a_2$ and produce any *chosen* value of $a_3$ for $i=3$.

More generally, I suppose I would define a *rule* to be the ability to produce on demand any given term of a sequence. Given some $S$ with $\lambda = n$, if we are requested to produce the $m^{\mathrm{th}}$ term of $S$, there are infinitely many degree $n+1$ polynomials (one for each possible choice of the $m^{\mathrm{th}}$ term) that can serve as a rule to our $S$. Then if we are requested to produce some other term, we can choose any of the infinitely many degree $n+2$ polynomials that satisfies the terms we have so far and give us then next requested term. Et cetera.

This doesn't quite work, though, if we allow $\lambda$ to be infinite.

Comment: I suspect by intuition it is easy to understand why $\lambda \rightarrow \infty$ does not work, since there's only one possible rule to fit infinite many given terms

But how to prove it rigorously (as in the approach to the proof, i.e. what are the considerations needed to formulate the proof?)

Also is there exist a cutoff point where it "just/borderline" does not work before tending to some countable infinity? (Not sure if I understood it correctly...). that is is there exist a

Comment: (Ignore the "Also...exist a", it's a wrong comment)

The corrected version: Why do we need to have a n+1 deg polynomial to fit n given terms, is it because we need an extra coefficient to set the n+1th term and the other n coefficients were used to fit the given n terms?

Comment: @Yeah, we need a degree $n+1$ polynomial to fit our $n$ given terms and to fit whatever term we want to be our $n+1^{\mathrm{th}}$ term. Also, there may be some way still to have infinitely many rules with $\lambda = \infty$. It is just that my polynomial idea won't work with it because you can't (in this case) have an infinite degree polynomial.